# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php

```
class Affiliates_Shortcodes {

    private $earnings;


    public static function affiliates_user_tree() {

echo $this->earnings;

        }   
    }
```

Getting error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: A static function has no relation to an object, so you cannot use `$this` in any static context.

Comment: so how to access it

Comment: `echo self::earnings` - but $earnings must be declared static also!

Comment: `public static function` Declare your function not to be static

Comment: `static` means that your function is not applied on an object; so if you really need to access `$this`, you will need to remove `static` keyword

Answer (score 2):

Your method is declared as `static`. You can't use object properties within static methods. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php